# aws s3 bucket files locked out, cant add permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-s3

i recently transferred a couple of s3 buckets to a different account with s3cmd from the master :(

now i cant access any of the files transferred to these buckets since there is no way i can add permissions to these transferred files. when i try to add permissions to these files i get. Sorry! You were denied access to do that even when I'm the admin!

no way to add permissions to files : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOB8W.jpg

I have tried to add everyone permission in the bucket itself but all in vain.

I'll appreciate if anyone can help me to retrieve these files.

Comment: I'm no sure, just add "Authenticated Users" permission in the master account and try to access the files again

Comment: I am suffering from the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ThiagoFassina no solution. aws sucks! i moved out of it!

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem and it turned to be the permissions set to the files when copying the files over. I was using the PHP library provided by Amazon, and when calling the copy method the permissions needed to be set to "bucket-owner-full-control". That worked for me. You are probably copying your stuff in a different manner, but maybe this is the path to follow.

I started to find the solution reading [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944054/cant-download-files-uploaded-by-shared-account-s3-bucket).